# CSS is not working?

Tags: css, linux, wordpress, apache2, debian

I've managed it to get my Debian server with Apache2 under VestaCP running, but there's another problem.

When I try to install WordPress, nothing but plain text is shown, as css wouldn't even load (so I dont know, if the title's being correct) and yea, no design at all.

Take a look here: https://www.mrxidevelopment.de/img/i14397482092008.png

Also, after installing through that plain text stuff, I can't login.

Is that a misconfiguration of apache or have I disabled css anywhere?

Regards

Comment: Use Browser's dev tools(F12) and check there is any error while loading the CSS files.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam how to check if I've pressed F12?

Answer (score 0):

One issue could be the serving up of resources over HTTPS. For example, you main site contains very many absolute paths. Maybe you had a reason for this, but it can lead to problems :)

If you change:

```
    href="http://[whatever the uri is].css"
```

To:

```
    href="//[whatever the css uri is].css"
```

You will then have 'protocol relative' paths.

Another pointer is using Firefox with the FireBug extension installed. You can find it [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Finally, under WordPress General Settings you can change the WordPress Address (URL) and the Site Address (URL) from HTTP to HTTPS. If you don't have access to your admin you can change this via your wp-config.php, [see here for guidance on doing so.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

> EDIT

The issue is the paths supplied for your resources.

Try right clicking in the browser and selecting `View Source`. See the  tag of your page. It contains all stylesheet and javascript includes.

At present, all paths are prefixed with `http://` which will not work over the HTTPS protocol. My point here is to use protocol relative paths.

For example, in the Inspector (within Firefox) I changed the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="twentyfifteen-style-css" href="http://www.mrxidevelopment.de/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css?ver=4.2.4" type="text/css" media="all">
```

To

```
<link href="//www.mrxidevelopment.de/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css?ver=4.2.4" rel="stylesheet" id="twentyfifteen-style-css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

The change rendered your page in my browser like this:

[image]

Note the `href=` attribute was the only change - but it enables  successful location and load of the CSS file.

You will need to do the same for any other resources you wish to include (i.e. Images, CSS and JS etc.)

For more information see the SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446314/why-use-protocol-relative-urls-at-all) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940525/css-styles-disappear-over-ssl).

> Just for clarity
>
> Changing the `href` attribute within the Inspector (or other browser tools) is not permanent - but is a great for debugging.
>
> To permanently fix the paths open up your source in an editor [Sublime Text is great for this](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and edit your mark-up.
>
> Let me know if you need any further help mate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that with Firefox. But, where do I need to change the first mentioned thing with the whatever the css uri is...?Regards

Comment: well, I tried to call it normally (without https) it's working https://www.mrxidevelopment.de/img/i14398061551208.png, but how to solve that?!

Comment: See my updated answer - also this issue is fairly common - see other SO post :)